# Simplify .to_json array result in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code:

```
@post.to_json(include: {tags: { only: :name} } )
```

which produces this output:

```
{ ... "tags": [{"name": "Lorem"}, {"name": "ipsum"}, {"name": "cupcake"}] ... }
```

When what I want  is:

```
{ ... "tags": ["Lorem", "ipsum", "cupcake"] ... }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, write your own serializer rather than trying to hack the `to_json`.

```
class PostWithTagsSerializer
  attr_reader :object

  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def as_json(*)
    hash = object.as_json
    hash[:tags] = object.tags.pluck(:name)
    hash
  end

  def to_json(*)
    as_json.to_json
  edn
end
```

Then simply use

```
PostWithTagsSerializer.new(@post).to_json
```